# How can I configure logtash to use "stdout" as input?

Tags: linux, configuration, docker, stdout, logstash

I have following setup:

1. 4 Docker containers which are configured to send logs to "stdout".
2. 1 Docker container running logstash.

Now I want to configure logstash to use the "stdout" from the 4 docker containers as input. I am not planning to use logstash-forwarder now since I am just trying to setup a very basic configuration. I might switch to forwarder at a later stage.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209173901/https://evanhazlett.com/2014/11/Logging-with-ELK-and-Docker/). This guy use `logspout` lib for listen stdout from all of your containers and put it to logstash. If you have another solution, please send me feedback, because i am in 
search too.