# How to get Stdout from a service into logstash

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I understand that a similar question was asked here:
[How can I configure logtash to use "stdout" as input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479311/how-can-i-configure-logtash-to-use-stdout-as-input), but I wanted to generalize the question a little.

What I have currently configured is the basic ELK stack(elasticSearch, logstash, kibana) on a Linux VM and I want to feed a bit of standard output into logstash in order to remove log files from the file system, thus not consuming disk space.

So for example, how would I take the std-out from say, Kibana, and feed that directly into Logstash?

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. If you connect, say, Kibana's stdout to Logstash's stdin, if you restart Kibana you'll have to restart Logstash and vice versa. Also, if Logstash's pipeline gets clogged (e.g. because a downstream host is unavailable) the pipe's buffer will eventually fill up and the process writing its logs to stdout will block (if its logging is synchronous; otherwise you'll only see log messages dropped on the floor).

I suggest you use disk-based logging but rotate the files aggressively.

Comment: I ended up redirecting my Kibana stdout to a tcp server that was specified in the logstash config.  Has not caused any issues when restarting Kibana itself.  I am simply tinkering with the stack not quite being used in production yet.

Comment: Now that we are two years later, would you still recommend this solution? Did you observe any problems or bottlenecks?